# Why css animation is not working with a toggle button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple switch button with CSS and JavaScript, I need a animation while the button is toggling or clicked. I have only the animation problem nothing else. 
Is there any problem with the positioning (relative, absolute)? But as I know css property `left` has animation, Then why here this is not working?

```js
(function (){
  
  let 
  
      btn = document.querySelector ('.input-switch'),
      container = document.querySelector ('.input-switch-container'),
      checkbox = container.querySelector ('input[type="checkbox"]');
  
  btn.addEventListener ('click', function (){  
    container.classList.toggle('active');
    checkbox.checked ?  checkbox.checked = false :  checkbox.checked = true;
  });
  
}())
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input-switch{
  border-radius: .25rem;
  width: 112px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.input-switch-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  transition: all 1.3s linear;
}

.input-switch-container.active{
  left: -56px;
}

.input-switch-on,  
.input-switch-off,
.input-switch-empty{
  padding: .25rem 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  flex: 0 0 50%; 
}

.input-switch-on{
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
}

.input-switch-off{
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.input-switch-empty{
  background-color: #fff;
}

.input-switch input[type="checkbox"]{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-switch">
  <div class="input-switch-container">
    <span class="input-switch-on">ON</span>
    <span class="input-switch-empty"></span>
    <span class="input-switch-off">OFF</span>
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because your initial state `.input-switch-container` doesn't have a left value set. CSS doesn't know what value to start at, unless you set it. Add `left: 0` to test.

Comment: @Disinfor You are right. I missed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `.input-switch-container` an initial `left` value.

```js
(function (){
  
  let 
  
      btn = document.querySelector ('.input-switch'),
      container = document.querySelector ('.input-switch-container'),
      checkbox = container.querySelector ('input[type="checkbox"]');
  
  btn.addEventListener ('click', function (){  
    container.classList.toggle('active');
    checkbox.checked ?  checkbox.checked = false :  checkbox.checked = true;
  });
  
}())
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input-switch{
  border-radius: .25rem;
  width: 112px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.input-switch-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  transition: all 1.3s linear;
  left: 0;
}

.input-switch-container.active{
  left: -56px;
}

.input-switch-on,  
.input-switch-off,
.input-switch-empty{
  padding: .25rem 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  flex: 0 0 50%; 
}

.input-switch-on{
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
}

.input-switch-off{
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.input-switch-empty{
  background-color: #fff;
}

.input-switch input[type="checkbox"]{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-switch">
  <div class="input-switch-container">
    <span class="input-switch-on">ON</span>
    <span class="input-switch-empty"></span>
    <span class="input-switch-off">OFF</span>
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </div>
</div>
```

You could achieve the same results without any javascript if you rearrange the HTML and make a few changes to your CSS.

The important part of the CSS is this:

```
.input-switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .input-switch-container {
  left: -56px;
}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input-switch{
  border-radius: .25rem;
  width: 112px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  display: block;
}

.input-switch-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  left: 0;
}

.input-switch-on,  
.input-switch-off,
.input-switch-empty{
  padding: .25rem 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  flex: 0 0 50%; 
}

.input-switch-on{
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
}

.input-switch-off{
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.input-switch-empty{
  background-color: #fff;
}

.input-switch input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.input-switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .input-switch-container {
  left: -56px;
}
```

```html
<label class="input-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <div class="input-switch-container">
    <span class="input-switch-on">ON</span>
    <span class="input-switch-empty"></span>
    <span class="input-switch-off">OFF</span>
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: You are really awesome person.  I think I need rest, I don't even saw this. I knew that I need a initialized value for css animation. So sad :(

Comment: I am satisfied. (Is there any good resource to learn advance CSS not W3Schools or SoloLearn or FreeCodeCamp?)

Comment: MDN and StackOverflow provide the answers to anything I ever need to know.